# aws cloud formation | creating ecs service with its own capacity provider fails. Fails at capacity provider association to cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Scenario:
ECS Cluster exists with one service using EC2 capacity provider

Attempting to create new service in same cluster along with new capacity provider. The association of capacity provider to cluster fails.\

came across articles like this https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/631 which does say it is supported but not helpful.
Note: new cluster with capacity provider association succeeds but fails to associate new capacity provider to existing cluster.

This seems to be a bug to me. Any insights will be much appreciated.

Simplest example is below.

1. Create cluster
   aws ecs create-cluster --cluster-name my-test-cluster --region us-eas
2. cloud foundation template for a) create asg b) create capacity provider c) associate to cluster

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "The template used to create an ECS Cluster for nocohub paid workspace",
    "Parameters": {       
        "LaunchTemplateId": {
            "Description": "AMI ID",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "lt-04cde001adead75f6"
          },
          "SubnetIds": {
            "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
            "Description": "Optional - Specifies the Comma separated list of existing VPC Subnet Ids where ECS instances will run",
            "Default": "subnet-0f815721f89468e42"
          }
    },
    "Resources": {           
        "ASG": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties": {
              "AutoScalingGroupName" : "my-test-cluster", 
              "MinSize": "1",
              "MaxSize": "4",
              "DesiredCapacity": "1",
              "LaunchTemplate": {
                "LaunchTemplateId": {
                    "Ref": "LaunchTemplateId"
                },                
                "Version": "1"
              },
              "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
                "Ref": "SubnetIds"
              }
            }
          },
          
      "EC2CapacityProvider": {        
        "Type": "AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider",

        "Properties": {
          "Name" : "my-test-capacity-provider",
          "AutoScalingGroupProvider": {
            "AutoScalingGroupArn": {
                "Ref" : "ASG"
            },
            "ManagedScaling": {
              "Status": "ENABLED",
              "TargetCapacity": 100
            },
            "ManagedTerminationProtection": "DISABLED"
          }
        }
      },
      "ClusterCPAssociation": {
        "Type": "AWS::ECS::ClusterCapacityProviderAssociations",
        "Properties": {
          "Cluster": "my-test-cluster",
          "CapacityProviders": [
            "FARGATE","FARGATE_SPOT",            
            {
              "Ref": "EC2CapacityProvider"
            }
          ],
          "DefaultCapacityProviderStrategy": []
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Below is the error and screenshot
`my-test-cluster already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:249717198246:stack/asdfasda/1e8230a0-b369-11ed-8adf-06ccee440287`
[Cloud formation stack event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FwtO.png)
if you are testing above stack then

- you will need to provide a subnetId and launch template(with security group associated to same subnet)
- first run works as its the first ClusterCPAssociation, when you attempt to create new one then it fails.
  ClusterCPAssociation is not separate entity and cfn does not have good support for updating existing resources along with new create. (let me know if my understanding is not correct here)